# How do I make line string in leaflet-realtime with marker on every point?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want something like below image:
[image]
Don't know where to define linestring. It would be great if anyone can guide me. Moreover I want to change the color of linestring.
Here is my code:-

```
function createRealtimeLayer(url, container) {
    return L.realtime(url, {
        interval: 5 * 1000,
        getFeatureId: function(f) {
            return f.properties.id;
        },
        cache: true,
        container: container,
        onEachFeature(f, l) {
            date = f.properties.date;
            l.bindPopup(date);
            l.on("mouseover", function () {
                l.openPopup();
            });
            l.on("mouseout", function () {
                l.closePopup();
            });
        }
    });
}
    realtime1 = createRealtimeLayer('getPosition').addTo(map),
    realtime2 = createRealtimeLayer('getUserPositionHistory').addTo(map);

L.control.layers(null, {
    'Current': realtime1,
    'History': realtime2
}).addTo(map);

realtime1.once('update', function() {
    map.fitBounds(realtime1.getBounds(), {maxZoom: 18});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the markers on every point add this to your onEachFeature:

```
if(layer instanceof L.Path){      
      l.getLatLngs().forEach(function(latlng){
        L.marker(latlng).addTo(map);
      })
    }
```

if you want to colorize your line, you have to split up your line like that, but then append not the geojson layer to the map:

```
if(layer instanceof L.Path){
      var lastlatlng = null;
      layer.getLatLngs().forEach(function(latlng, i){
        if(lastlatlng !== null){
             L.polyline([lastlatlng,latlng],{color: getColor(i)}).addTo(map);
        }
        lastlatlng = latlng;
      })
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

The Asker wants to create a Line by points from the geojson.

You can add latlngs from the points to a polyline with `poly.addLatLng(latlng)`

```
var oldcolor = null;
var polys = [];

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    if(feature.properties.color && oldcolor != feature.properties.color){
        oldcolor = feature.properties.color;

      var lastlatlng = [];

      //This block gets the last latlng from the line before. so you have one line.
      // If you  want to seperate the lines by color, deleted this block
      if( polys.length > 0){
        var lastpoly = polys[polys.length-1];
        if(lastpoly.getLatLngs() && lastpoly.getLatLngs().length > 0){
          var lastlatlngs = lastpoly.getLatLngs();
          lastlatlng = lastlatlngs[0][lastlatlngs[0].length-1];
        }
      }
      //End of block

      polys.push(L.polyline([lastlatlng],{color: oldcolor}).addTo(mymap));
    }

    var poly = polys[polys.length-1]; //get last line
    poly.addLatLng(layer.getLatLng());
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/pksy6o8v/

Comment: Thank you for your time but I am able to show marker at every point but how to add points and show it as a linestring like a trail.

Comment: https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator then this is the right library for you

Comment: But the problem is data is in point. It is like this:-

{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[77.206323,28.564685]},"properties":{"date":"02-12-2019 02:48:59","id":1}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[78.206323,29.564685]},"properties":{"date":"02-12-2019 02:49:01","id":2}}]}

Comment: Thank You. I will try to implement it.

Comment: Please help. I am getting this error `poly.addLatLng is not a function`

Comment: Have you created a poly? `var poly = L.polyline([]).addTo(map)`

Comment: Yes, I have pushed the data as you did in the fiddle `polys.push(L.polyline([lastlatlng],{color: oldcolor}).addTo(map));`

Comment: I make it work but one problem it doesn't update line automatically there is a new entry in the database. I am calling API every specified second.

Comment: Try to set ` cache: false`. Also if you get all points you can call at the beginning of onEachFeature `map.clearLayers` and `polys = []` to reset all and then add it new to the map. If you get only points, the code should work. 

Also pls check the Answer, because the main question is answered.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. But my question was different. I want these things to work with the leaflet-realtime plugin. As of now only markers are updating and clearing when a new entry is recorded in the database without reloading. I have to make it work with a polyline.

Comment: Your Question was how you make a polyline with markers/points ... maybe the function `updateFeature` from the L.realtime library helps you. Create a working https://jsfiddle.net/ with all urls etc. then i can help you more but with this information i have now, i have not the possibility to help you

Comment: Ok, Here is working jsfiddle link. Now I want to join these markers and remove line when any point get deleted.
https://jsfiddle.net/alia02/seby1mcv/16/
Thank You.

Comment: look into: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/0p39nr7g/ I can not do more for you.

Comment: Just one question why did you use `feature.properties.net` can't I use ID? What is the usage can you explain, please.

Comment: I used the `net`property because it was the only property to get the same markers. If you use the ID, no polylines are created, because each ID is unique. If you find a property with that you can filter out which markers belongs together.

And pls upvote or check my answer. I had done a lot of work for you

Comment: Thank You. Your answer is very helpful. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: One more favour I don't have any net property. It was dummy data as I was unable to link my original data. Can I use color instead of `net` property,

Comment: Here is the original data `{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[77.17929,30.646605]},"properties":{"date":"06-12-2019 04:58:33","id":3,"color":"rgb(4,98,164)"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[77.17929,28.646605]},"properties":{"date":"07-12-2019 04:58:32","id":1,"color":"rgb(4,66,132)"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[77.17929,29.646605]},"properties":{"date":"07-12-2019 04:58:33","id":2,"color":"rgb(4,66,132)"}}]}`

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. Now it works with the color property. It would be greate if you check my answer...

Comment: Thank you so much. Means there is no way to link all coordinates with a different colour. It will always bunch together with those whose colour is the same ? Sorry for disturbing you so much and really thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yeah the color is the connector